# Compiler generated assembly segfaults to read integer

Tags: segmentation-fault, compiler-construction, scheme, x86-64

I'm trying to implement a compiler for a subset of Scheme to x86-64 following [this](https://github.com/IUCompilerCourse/Essentials-of-Compilation) book. For this program

```
(let ([x (read)])
  (let ([y (read)])
    (if (if (< x 1) (eq? x 0) (eq? x 2))
      (+ y 2)
      (+ y 10))))
```

my compiler generates

```
start:
    callq read_int
    movq %rax, %rbx
    jmp block34954
    .globl main
block34954:
    callq read_int
    movq %rax, %rcx
    jmp block34953
block34953:
    cmpq $1, %rbx
    jl block34951
    jmp block34952
block34951:
    cmpq $0, %rbx
    je block34949
    jmp block34950
block34952:
    cmpq $2, %rbx
    je block34949
    jmp block34950
block34949:
    movq %rcx, %rax
    addq $2, %rax
    jmp conclusion
block34950:
    movq %rcx, %rax
    addq $10, %rax
    jmp conclusion
main:
    pushq %rbp
    pushq %rbx
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    subq $16, %rsp
    jmp start
conclusion:
    addq $16, %rsp
    popq %rbx
    popq %rbp
    retq
```

where `read_int` reads an integer from the standard input and puts it into `rax`.
From what I understand, my compiler is assigning `rbx` to `x` and `rcx` to `y` and since `rbx` is a callee saved register, it also pushes/pops it off the stack in the `main`/`conclusion` blocks. Furthermore, since stack frames must be 16-byte aligned, it adds/subtracts 16 bytes to account for the pushes/pops in the `main`/`conclusion` blocks.

However, this program gives me a segfault and running it in gdb says

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /<path>/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e1a3e9 in __vfscanf_internal () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

which I am unsure what to make of.

I don't understand why this segfaults, any help would be appreciated.

[Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IUCompilerCourse/public-student-support-code/master/runtime.c) is the runtime that has `read_int`.

Comment: tl;dr of dupe: The AMD64 SysV ABI requires the stack to be 16-byte aligned when you call functions, but you're calling them with it only 8-byte aligned.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica thank you! That indeed solved the issue. May I know what/how you searched for this error to get that answer?

Comment: I didn't search for anything. I recognized the problem by looking at your code.